# What is the probability that at least one suitcase ends up with its original traveller?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, derangements

There are  travellers who have $n$ identical suitcases which they unwittingly did not label, and there suitcases are arriving on the baggage carousel. Each traveller selects a suitcase at random, being unable to tell it apart from all the others.

What is the probability that at least one suitcase ends up with its original traveller?

Comment: Do complementary counting: Find the probability $p$ that no suitcase ends up with its original traveller, and the probability that at least one suitcase ends up with its original traveller is $1-p$.

Comment: So the way I'm thinking no one gets the right suitcase is when each of the 1,...n people have (n-1) suitcases to choose from, so the probability of 1 person not getting the right suitcase is (n-1)Cn = (n-1)/n. So probability no one gets the right suitcase is $(\frac{n-1}{n})^n$. Is this right?

Comment: @MB1001 Have a look at [derangements](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). What you suggest is not correct because there is no independence.